# javascript high level charting api based on d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I love the flexibility of [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), but in some cases its low level api is hard to use. What are some higher level charting libraries based on d3.js? I know on [rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) so far.

Comment: Have a look at http://nvd3.com/

Comment: Thanks, post an answer on this and I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you I have been very impressed by D3, but found it tricky.

The best D3 charting library I've seen is [NVD3.js](http://nvd3.org/).  I've been testing it out, but not yet used it in anger.

Currently I'm working on the theory that to get the best out of D3 you need a strong understanding of JavaScript, so I'm brushing up on my [JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do), which I'm finding very helpful.

Comment: Loved the phrase 'not yet used in anger'.